# Check if list is sorted Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am trying to solve a homework assignment. This is the assighnment:
Write the in_order() function, which has a list of integers as a parameter, and returns True if the integers are sorted (in order from low to high) or False otherwise. The program outputs "In order" if the list is sorted, or "Not in order" if the list is not sorted.

Ex: If the list passed to the in_order() function is [5, 6, 7, 8, 3], then the function returns False and the program outputs:

Not in order
Ex: If the list passed to the in_order() function is [5, 6, 7, 8, 10], then the function returns True and the program outputs:

In order
Note: Use a for loop. DO NOT use sorted() or sort().

And this is the code I have so far

```
def in_order(nums):
in_order = True
previous = check[0]
for item in check[1:]:
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        nums1 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 3]
    if in_order(nums1):
        print('In order')
    else:
        print('Not in order') 
nums2 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 10]
if in_order(nums2):
    print('In order')
else:
    print('Not in order')
```

Comment: It seems that your code has some issues - formatting or logic?  It could be simplified by taking advantage of comparing 2 numbers - eg. prev. vs next directly using built-in **zip**.

Answer (score 0):

Does the `for` need to be a separate statement, or can it be part of a generator expression?

```
def in_order(nums):
    return all(nums[i-1] < nums[i] for i in range(1, len(nums)))
```

Comment: Part of the generated expression. The output needs to have 'In order' and 'Not in order'

Comment: Even it's very pythonic way to use all(), but did not address  the PO question.

Comment: @BenBoulay you said "the program" needs to generate the output, not the function.  Functions should be as limited as possible in what they do, to make them simpler and easier to understand.

Comment: @DanielHao the OP did not actually ask a question, the closest they came was "Write the in_order() function".  Is that not what I did?

Answer (score -1):

I guessed my way through this question using Mark's code. I changed it and found the code below works to solve the problem. I'm not too sure why.

```
def in_order(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[i-1] < nums[i]:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Comment: It actually doesn't work at all.  It returns after checking the first two elements without checking any of the others.  If it worked for you, it's because you didn't have good test data.  The example `[5, 6, 7, 8, 3]` from the question will fail.